# Guidance on mapping the following relationship with ebean using jpa annotations

Tags: java, jpa, ebean

I have the following two entities in the DB ( structure is fixed ) which I am trying to map using JPA Annotations and EBEAN is ORM.

I have the following beans:

```
class Item {
   public Long id;
   public String name;
   public Consignee intermediate;
   public Consignee ultimate;
}

class Consignee {
   public Long id;
   public String name;
   public String address;
   public Item item;
}
```

And their corresponding tables:

```
Item
----
id
name

Consignee
---------
id:
name
address
item_id
type: [1,2] / 1: intermediate, 2:ultimate
```

the main entity is ITEM although the relationship is mapped from the consignee side.

How can I mapped this using the Annotations so that the consignees ( ultimate, intermediate ) are loaded when I fetch the Item object from DB ?

Could you please point me to the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two tables your are trying to map to Ebean are called Entity Models and the relation between Entity Consignee to Item is a One to Many Relationship.

Such relation can be mapped with a `@OneToMany` annotation on the Consignee side, and with an `@ManyToOne` on the Item side.

Also the field type of Consignee can be mapped with an Enumeration persisted as integer, and the remaining fields can be mapped via `@Column` annotation.

A possible implementation of your requirements could be something like:

```
public enum CONSIGNEE_TYPE {
      INTERMEDIATE,
      ULTIMATE
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Consignee")
public class Consignee extends Model {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   public Long id;

   public String name;

   public String address;

   @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
   public CONSIGNEE_TYPE type;

   @Column(name="item_id")
   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "consignee", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   public List<Item> item = new ArrayList<Item>();

   //TODO: Generate Constructors/Getters/Setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Item")
public class Item extends Model {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   public Long id;

   public String name;

   @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   public Consignee consignee = new Consignee();

   //TODO: Generate Constructors/Getters/Setters
}
```

I removed the ambiguation with the ultimate and intermediate consignee type from the class Item since you can store the type of the consignee on the consignee itself.

Hope this helps.

As a very nice resource for the future, I recommend you to read the Unit Tests available on the source code of the Ebean itself. It ain't pretty but it helped me a lot!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write such a nice answer! It is a great idea to read the unit tests I will do them right now. Thanks again!

Comment: Also the additional complexity is the following for me. Each consigne can have 1..n ultimate and intermediate consignees.

Comment: @Istvano You will need an association of N-to-N for that. This is, you will need to create a class with consignee source and target (fields of type Consignee). Then on Consignee you will need the properties 'consigneeAssociations' (1-N) and 'associatedWith' (N-1). The association class would have the multiplicities (1-N) for source and (1-N) for target. But N-N on Ebean is new different topic, as there is much to say about it :) .